# how to make the remotedesktop and local connection work together

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

I want to allow connection to my desktop while I work on it too. currently if someone remotely logs on to my computer, I cant work on it then. Is there a way around. thanks

Comment: If your OS is Windows Server2003, then someone else logging on should not be a problem, unless they are logging into the console session???

Comment: This looks like a question for http://serverfault.com/, as it is non-programming related.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/06/13/enable-multiple-concurrent-remote-desktop-connections-or-sessions-in-windows-xp/

Comment: this works, unfortunately a windows update normally un-fixes it for you eventually.